# case expression to change the value of a column

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two columns are `measurement_unit` and `measurement_size`.The values in  `measurement_unit` column are `ml,gm,litre`.And `measurement_size` has the values `200,1300,2000`i have converted all values of `measurement_size` to round figure such as `.2,1.3,2` now i want to change the values of `measurement_unit` to `liter` or `kg` and here is my case expression .But it is not working..what should i do?In addition it is not a update query i am doing this for my report..it will not change any value in database..

```
 CASE WHEN MUC.name='ml' THEN (MUC.name)='Liter' 
    WHEN MUC.name='gm' THEN (MUC.name)='Kg' 
    END AS Measurement,
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possibility would be to use a `CASE WHEN` inside an `UPDATE` statement:

```
UPDATE MUC
SET MUC.name = CASE
    WHEN MUC.name = 'ml' THEN 'Liter';
    WHEN MUC.name = 'gm' THEN 'Kg';
ELSE MUC.name
END
```

The only thing I don't like about this solution is that it will still update a row which does not match, using the current value.  If you really only want to update the rows which you intend to convert, then you can try using two `UPDATE` statements, wrapped in a transaction:

```
START TRANSACTION
    UPDATE MUC
    SET MUC.name = 'Liter' WHERE MUC.name = 'ml'
    UPDATE MUC
    SET MUC.name = 'Kg' WHERE MUC.name = 'gm'
COMMIT
```

The transaction might be necessary if you want to ensure that no one ever sees your units in an intermediate state.

Comment: But what is solution of this column measurement_size??

Answer (score 1):

You can try this.

```
select 
CASE WHEN M_unit='ml' THEN 'Liter' 
    WHEN M_unit.name='gm' THEN 'Kg'
    ELSE M_UNIT 
    END AS Measurement_UNIT,
M_size/1000 as Measurement_SIZE
 from Table
```